# How to add/modify toolbar icons on Thunar 1.6.11?

Tags: 16.04, thunar, button, tools

I currently switching from KDE to XFCE4 and starting to miss several useful toolbar buttons in Thunar, which I like in Dolphin.

*Yes, I understand, that I can us Dolphin on xfce, but it runs much slower on my pc than thunar.*

So I want to find tool to adjust the thunar itself.